# how to call constructor class method by calling constructor

Tags: apex, constructor, oop

i want to load wrapper class with one shot, but I couldn't able. may be still my oops skills are weak. i feel we can write much better way

```
 public class WrapperA{
    public Id sobjerecid;
    public sobjrec__c sobjrec;
    public classA classobjA;
     public classB classobjB;
    public WrapperA(Id recid){
        this.sobjerecid= recId;
        this.sobjrec = [Select Id,xy__c,ab__c,sss_c,bb__c,ccc__c from sobjec__c where Id =:recid Limit 1];
        this.prepareclassA();
        this.prepareclassobjB(); 
        
    }
    private void prepareclassA (){
    classA classaobj = new classA();
        
    classaobj.bf = 'spi';
    classaobj.Sc= 'xyz';
    classaobj.RS= 'abc';
    classaobj.SS= '123q';
    this.classobjA = classaobj;

}
    
    private void prepareclassobjB(){
    classB  classBobj = new classB();
    innerclassofclassB[] innerclassBlistobj  = new List<innerclassofclassB>();
    innerclassofclassB innerclassBobj= new innerclassofclassB();

    classBobj.prop1= sobjrec.xy__c;
    classBobj.prop2=sobjrec.ab__c;
    classBobj.prop3 =sobjrec.sss_c;
           
    innerclassBobj.innerclassBprop1= sobjrec.bb__c;
    innerclassBobj.innerclassBprop2= sobjrec.ccc__c;
    
   
    innerclassBlistobj.add(innerclassBobj);
    classBobj.InnerclassB= innerclassBlistobj;

    this.classobjB= classBobj;
}
    
}

public mainClass {
  WrapperA wrapA = new WrapA(recId);// i want to load etire wrapper object with this line
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constructors are typically called by using the `new` keyword. There's also `super()` and `this()`, but those probably aren't what you're looking for (`super()` is used to call the parent class's constructor, `this()` is used when a single class has multiple constructors to help re-use code).

Your `prepareClassA()` and `prepareClassObjB()` methods look like they should be constructors in `ClassA` and `ClassB` respectively (with the constructor for ClassB taking an argument so you can set prop1, prop2, and prop3).

In the end, your wrapper constructor should just simply do the following

```java
public class WrapperA{
    // member vars remain unchanged

    public WrapperA(Id recId){
        // unaffected code unchanged
        classObjA = new classA();
        classObjB = new classB(sobjRec);
    }

    // no extra methods to set up ClassObjA or B
    // that's the responsibility of the constructors for those classes

}
```

That'd work, but that general approach (creating object instances used by a class *inside of the same class*) makes for code that is more fragile and harder to test. If `classA` changes so that it no longer has a no-arg constructor, you'd need to also change your wrapper class.

It may not matter so much in this case, but the generally accepted practice is to inject dependencies into a class (as opposed to creating things in the class). Unsurprisingly, this concept is called *dependency injection*. If you get the feeling that you're just shifting code around (it's taking code that was part of the wrapper, and forcing it to be done in the thing that creates/uses the wrapper), that's because that is *exactly* what you're doing.

The benefit of doing that, however, is that it helps to isolate changes. Changing how `ClassB` works no longer means that `WapperA` needs to change as well.

Applied to your wrapper class...

```java
public class WrapperA{
    // It doesn't appear that sobjRec__c is used for anything besides getting
    //   data into the ClassB instance.
    // Since we're using dependency injection, other code will worry about getting
    //   the right data for ClassB, so we don't need to worry about it here
    public ClassA myAInstance;
    public ClassB myBInstance;
    
    public WrapperA(ClassA aInstance, ClassB bInstance){
        myAInstance = aInstance;
        myBInstance = bInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks well formatted answer, but where should i set `sobjrec__c` , do i need to prepare `sobjrec__c`  record before calling my wrapper constructor? that means i need to call classB constructor with `sobjrec__c` record then call wrapper constructor with  classB instance is it right?

Comment: @sdandamud1 In my first example, there is no change to how you get your `sobjrec__c` instance. In my second example (dependency injection), `sobjrec__c` is no longer needed in the wrapper class and your order of operations sounds correct (get an `sobjectrec__c` instance, pass it to the `ClassB` constructor, call the `ClassA` constructor, pass both ClassA and ClassB instances to your wrapper's constructor).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Derek's answer, consider the builder pattern

```
public class WrapperA {

  ClassA classA
  ClassB classB

  public WrapperA withclassA(ClassA val)  {this.classA = val; return this;}
  public WrapperB withclassA(ClassB val)  {this.classB = val; return this;}
}

public class ClassA {
  String sc;
  String rs;
  String ss;
  public ClassA withSc(String val) {this.sc = val; return this;}
  public ClassA withRs(String val) {this.rs = val; return this;}
  public ClassA withSs(String val) {this.ss = val; return this;}
}

public class ClassB {
  .. similar to ClassA
}
```

and then you can instantiate in one statement

```
WrapperA wrapA = new WrapperA()
     .withClassA(new ClassA()
         .withRs('abc')
         .withSc('def'
         .withSS('ghi')
     )
     .withClassB(new ClassB()
          .withXX(..)
          ...
     );
```

This approach avoids too many arg methods that can be flagged by static code analyzers; is infinitely extensible, is very readable, avoids having to know the order of arguments, makes setting up testmethods easier, and provides other benefits of a facade between the object and how it is invoked (i.e. supporting default values)

Comment: this is the way i expect , thanks for wonderful answer